# Issue running homestead ssh command

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I've just managed to complete an install of the latest Laravel Homestead on Windows 7.
However I am stuck trying to run 'homestead ssh'.

The response I get is 'VAGRANT_DOTFILE_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to ssh to your box, go to the folder where homestead is installed and run:

```
vagrant ssh homestead
```

or if that is the only machine you spun up, then you can simply navigate to the folder where you stood up homestead and type

```
vagrant ssh
```

Also make sure your vagrant env is actually up after you have done the init and homestead installs.

```
vagrant up
```

Since you are doing this in Vagrant, you might find it helpful just to use basic Vagrant commands.

See vagrant docs:

https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix for homestead version 2.0.8 in windows enviroment.
https://github.com/maddhatter/homestead/commit/0ed6488eaebaaf7fffd5937f302ccc0ee421690c